# How to fill subsequent null values in pandas dataframe using previous rolling mean values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe like below.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({ 'month' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                  'temp'  : [50,60,40,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})

df
```

Output:

```
  month temp
0   1   50.0
1   2   60.0
2   3   40.0
3   4   NaN
4   5   NaN
5   6   NaN
```

I want to fill missing value using rolling average of previous two values. Now, in case of index 4(or month 5), I want to use calculated rolling mean at index 3 and index 2 value. So,

- temp at index 3: 50 (~ avg(60,40))
- temp at index 4: 45 (~ avg(40,50))

Expected output:

```
  month temp
0   1   50.0
1   2   60.0
2   3   40.0
3   4   50.0
4   5   45.0
5   6   47.5
```

I checked the documentation but there does not seem a way to do that. Any work around? Thank you.

Comment: Please post your expected output as well.

Comment: not very panda way, but solves the issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831334/pandas-fillna-and-rolling-mean

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @NoobVB, a similar question was already solved in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831334/pandas-fillna-and-rolling-mean) post. You just have to adjust the code according to your problem.
An alternative way to solve this for an extended version of your example data frame is given below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'month': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                'temp': [50,60,40,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,20,np.nan]})

series = df["temp"]
for i in range(series.isna().sum()):
  shifted_series = series.rolling(2).mean().shift(periods=1)
  series = series.combine_first(shifted_series)

df['new_temp'] = series

df

--------------------------------------------
    month   temp    new_temp
0   1       50.0    50.00
1   2       60.0    60.00
2   3       40.0    40.00
3   4       NaN     50.00
4   5       NaN     45.00
5   6       NaN     47.50
6   7       20.0    20.00
7   8       NaN     33.75
--------------------------------------------
```