# Filling NaN values with rolling mean of the previous non-NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, reduce

I have recently come across a case where I would like to replace `NaN` values with the rolling mean of the previous non-NaN values in such a way that each newly generated rolling mean is then considered a non-NaN and is used for the next NaN. This is the sample data set:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]})
df

   col1
0   1.0
1   3.0
2   4.0
3   5.0
4   6.0
5   NaN  # (6.0 + 5.0) / 2
6   NaN  # (5.5 + 6.0) / 2
7   NaN  # ...
```

I have also found a solution for this which I am struggling to understand:

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda x, _: x.fillna(x.rolling(2, min_periods=2).mean().shift()), range(df['col1'].isna().sum()), df)
```

My problem with this solution is `reduce` function takes 3 arguments, where we first define the lambda function then we specify the iterator. In the solution above I don't understand the last `df` we put in the function call for reduce and I struggle to understand how it works in general to populate the `NaN`.

I would appreciate any explanation of how it works. Also if there is any `pandas`, `numpy` based solution as `reduce` is not seemingly efficient here.

Comment: What about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831334/pandas-fillna-and-rolling-mean

Comment: I was hoping to see if there is way to do it with a for loop after I understand the current solution.

Comment: What is the actual window size in your real data set? if it is just a couple then some iteration will help

Comment: @PTQuoc It's 2, but it doesn't matter much. First I would like to understand the solution with reduce.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in df.index:
    if np.isnan(df["col1"][i]):
        df["col1"][i] = (df["col1"][i - 1] + df["col1"][i - 2]) / 2
```

This can be a start using for loop, it will fail if the first 2 values of the dataframe are **NAN**